# Get both network adapter active on Win7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Good morning All,

i'm trying to get the wired and wireless network adapter active (in order to use ForceBindIp) but when i connect the wired, the wireless adapter goes off and viceversa. I've just tried to check the advanced adapter setting from control panel, also in power management settings. There is nothing like "Disable adapter on wired connection".

Anybody know if there is a way to force this kind of behavior?

Regards,

Luca

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "goes off"? Do you mean it loses link? Or disables itself? Or what?

Comment: Hello Davide, of course. I mean it loses the link. The adapter is enable but  without connection to a net.

Comment: Now you've given two answers. Does it lots its connection to the net or does it lose link? These are two completely different failure modes. For example, if it loses its connection to the net, you should still be able to reach the router. If it loses link, you can't even send a packet at all.

Comment: Hello Davide, i think it loses link because if i check the wifi adapter is enable but without IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, but you should read [this post](http://supertechman.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/force-internet-connections-through-one.html).

You may want to read this post regarding NICS/Adapters [going to sleep](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/stop-network-adapter-from-getting-disabled-in-windows-7/).

This is helpful [routing programs via different NICS](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2975-network-adapters-using-multiple-programs-network-adapters.html).

This was intended as a general comment and may not answer your question.

Comment: Hello Michael and thanks, however, change all power settings: just tried and won't work for me; also changing the adapter metric value. In the netstat view my wired adapt have an highest metric then wireless adapter (also forcing the metric i have the same default metric). All the link posted have not solved my issue: when i connect a net adapter to the network the other lose connectivity. Other ideas?

Comment: @lucavb I'll come back to you!